# How do I attribute different color for each of the django model choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

Following is my models.py:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ("BUY", "Buy"),
        ("HOLD", "Hold"),
        ("SELL", "Sell"),
    )

remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choices, default="HOLD",  null=True)
```

Is there some way to attribute different color for each of the choices? For instance, if i choose "BUY" it is displayed in a color, say blue, on my html page.

EDIT:

Here's my complete models.py:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ("BUY", "Buy"),
        ("HOLD", "Hold"),
        ("SELL", "Sell"),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,  null=True, editable=True)
    buy_call = models.FloatField(null=True)
    target_price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    stop_loss = models.FloatField(null=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choices, default="HOLD",  null=True)
    sell_at = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Here's my views.py:

```
def table(request):
    table = Table.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    return render(request, 'scanner/table.html', {'table':table})
```

Here's my html:

```
 <tbody>
{% for i in table %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{i.name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.date.date}}</td>
        <td>{{i.buy_call}}</td>
        <td>{{i.target_price}}</td>
        <td>{{i.stop_loss}}</td>
        <td><strong>{{i.remarks}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{i.sell_at}}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your html template and css look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, update your views.py such that it passes your desired colors to the template.

```py
def table(request):
    table = Table.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    buycolor = "green"
    holdcolor = "yellow"
    sellcolor = "red"
    return render(request, 'scanner/table.html', {
       'table':table,
       'buycolor':buycolor,
       'holdcolor':holdcolor,
       'sellcolor':sellcolor
       })
```

Then, in your Django template, you can add this logic:

```html
{% if i.remarks == "BUY" %}
    <td style="color: {{buycolor}};"><strong>{{i.remarks}}</strong></td>
{% elif i.remarks == "HOLD" %}
    <td style="color: {{holdcolor}};"><strong>{{i.remarks}}</strong></td>
{% else %}
    <td style="color: {{sellcolor}};"><strong>{{i.remarks}}</strong></td>
{% endif %}
```

This checks what `i.remarks` is, then sets the color accordingly.

SIDENOTE: If you want to display Buy, Sell, Hold instead of BUY, SELL, HOLD, use `i.get_remarks_display()` instead of `i.remarks`.

Comment: Heyy, can u pls check my edit and then assist. Thank you!

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 96: 'elif', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: @Ramsey Had a typo in my answer, forgot the `%` in the first `if`. Try it again.

Comment: the error is gone but for some reason all the text (BUY, HOLD, SELL) are in red.

Comment: @Ramsey Wait, so your text is BUY, HOLD, SELL, and not Buy, Hold, Sell? I'll update my answer again.

Comment: big Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same challenge. I want to display the choices as "tags" in my application. The field can be displayed in different pages and I want it to be consistent accross all the application. I end up putting a @property field in the model:

```py
class Table(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ("BUY", "Buy"),
        ("HOLD", "Hold"),
        ("SELL", "Sell"),
    )

    ...

    @property
    def remarks_color(self):
        if self.remarks == "BUY":
             return "green"
        elif self.remarks == "HOLD":
             return "yellow"
        else:
             return "red"
```

Then in your template you can put the following code:

```html
<tbody>
{% for i in table %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{i.name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.date.date}}</td>
        <td>{{i.buy_call}}</td>
        <td>{{i.target_price}}</td>
        <td>{{i.stop_loss}}</td>
        <td style="color: {{i.remarks_color}};"><strong>{{i.remarks}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{i.sell_at}}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not totally sure that putting colors in the model is the right way to do things, but as far as I want consistency in all application I think this is the best solution.